# Android - MediaPlayer в сервисе и IllegalStateException

Tags: android-service, android, java, исключения, android-mediaplayer

Здравствуйте! У меня есть активити и сервис с плеером внутри. С помощью активити я хочу контролировать плеер в сервисе. Но мне всё время выкидывает исключение java.lang.IllegalStateException_
Вот код:

**MainActivity**

---

```
Player service;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//я вырезал код, который не имеет отношения к вопросу

servIntent = new Intent(FeatherPlayerActivity.this, Player.class);
connection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.e(tag, "Сервис подключен");
        if (!isTrayed) initialize();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
};
bindService(servIntent, connection, 0);
startService(servIntent);
service = new Player();
service.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); //просто пытаюсь определить плеер снова
}
```

---

**Player.class (Сервис)**

---

```
public class Player extends Service
{
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

public Player() {}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (mediaPlayer == null) mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    return new Binder();
}

public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}

public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
}
```

---

Что бы я не делал, всё равно выкидывает IllegalStateException_, когда я пытаюсь взаимодействоватть с плеером (service.mediaPlayer.(команда);). Помогите!!

---

LogCat

---

```
build.bootloader: unknown
build.brand: acer
build.cpu_abi: armeabi-v7a
build.cpu_abi2: armeabi
build.device: B1-A71
build.display: Acer_AV051_B1-A71_1.174.00_WW_GEN1
build.fingerprint: acer/B1-A71_ww_gen1/B1-A71:4.1.2/JZO54K/1361327270:user/release-keys
build.hardware: mt6517
build.host: asd1sd3
build.id: JZO54K
build.manufacturer: acer
build.model: B1-A71
build.product: B1-A71_ww_gen1
build.radio: unknown
build.serial: 31108826315
build.tags: release-keys
build.time: 1361327270000
build.type: user
build.user: root
version.codename: REL
version.incremental: eng.root.1361327219
version.release: 4.1.2
version.sdk_int: 16

11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1336)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at ru.vspr.FeatherPlayerActivity.loadMusic(FeatherPlayerActivity.java:332)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at ru.vspr.FeatherPlayerActivity.loadTrack(FeatherPlayerActivity.java:321)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at ru.vspr.FeatherPlayerActivity.initialize(FeatherPlayerActivity.java:185)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at ru.vspr.FeatherPlayerActivity.access$1000002(FeatherPlayerActivity.java)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at ru.vspr.FeatherPlayerActivity$100000000.onServiceConnected(FeatherPlayerActivity.java:72)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1127)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1144)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
11-10 11:42:14.727 E/AndroidRuntime(32280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Никто вам не поможет, пока вы не покажете стектрейс исключения.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, если я правильно понял смысл слова "стектрейс"

Comment: Гм. `service = new Player();` — так вы сервис не запустите.

Comment: Эт я определяю его, чтобы через переменную service взаимодействовать с плеером, а запускаю сервис кодом ниже: startService(servIntent);

Comment: Переменная `service`, представляющая собой экземпляр класса `Player` и запущенный сервис никак между собой не связаны. А для взаимодействия с сервисом используйте [AIDL][1].

  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Answer (score 1):

Советую внимательно почитать про сервисы и MediaPlayer.

[Сервисы](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Все делаете неправильно как-то.

Сложно сказать что-то конкретное c таким кодом, но есть ощущение что нужно следить за состоянием MediaPlayer. Вы вызываете reset или уже отreseteнного плеера или же еще незапущенного. Кроме того, нужно удалять ресурсы плеера, ставить в null его экземпляр, заново создавать его и после этого запускать. Во всяком случае лишним не будет. Внимательно посмотрите на схему состояний плеера в ссылке №2 и подправьте код работы с сервисом.